# In what forum would Iran sue Pakistan for damages?

Tags: international, jurisdiction, government-contracts

According to reports, Iran may claim $18 billion in damages from Pakistan for an unfinished pipeline if Pakistan does not complete its part of it as agreed. What forum would such a claim take place in?

Answer (score 4):

[According to reports](https://financialtribune.com/articles/energy/117363/tehran-to-take-islamabad-to-court-over-breach-of-gas-pipeline-deal), one potential forum is the [International Court of Arbitration](https://iccwbo.org/dispute-resolution/dispute-resolution-services/icc-international-court-of-arbitration/). All reports I see say that the agreement specifies that the forum will be an arbitration forum. Whether it can be *any* arbitration forum or if it must be the ICC, or can be selected from a list, depends on the specific wording of the Gas Sales and Purchase Agreement of 2009, which I have not been able to find.